# Problem when connecting to the socket server?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, blackberry, java-me

I made an application that connects to the socket server. I tested it successfully on blackberry devices on the edge connection. But I faced a problem in **ZAIN SA**. I am always getting **INVALID URL PARAMETERS** meaning that no internet connection is available.

In other countries, the connection is established. In **ZAIN SA** the connection is not established. What can be the problem? Note that the connection is successful on WIRELESS but not EDGE. How to resolve this? Is there a parameter I should include in the URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need the APN password for Zain SA.   Though it is called a 'password' they generally aren't kept secret, and the password is the same for all users on that network.

Comment: No this was not the problem. Thanks for your reply the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has anything to do with your code if it works on other carriers. It seems to me that it's a carrier specific problem and you will need to take it up with Zain engineers.

Having said that, if you post your code here we can have a look and see if there's anything obvious missing.